# Temp table: primary key with default name already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a following code in a stored procedure, **running inside a cursor**:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#newSales','U') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #newSales

CREATE TABLE #newSales
(
    AddressId INT NOT NULL,
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    Sale REAL NULL
)

/* some code here */

ALTER TABLE #newSales 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressId] ASC, [ItemId] ASC, [Date] ASC)
```

Periodically I get the following error (the name is different every time):

> There is already an object named 'PK__#newSale__34CE1EAA297D3472' in the database.

I have checked similar questions, but most of them are with explicitly named constraints. I can't understand how this can happen, because in this case the PK's name is generated automatically and in theory it must be unique (even with multiple connections calling this procedure).

What can be the source of the error?

Comment: Perhaps two threads are running the code at the same time.  Creating a table inside a cursor does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: I understand that if two threads are running the code then there will be 2 identical temp tables at the same time, but the autogenerated name must help with this, isn't it? I just don't know why the generated name is the same...
About the table in a cursor: why it's a bad idea? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating temporary tables where concurrency might be an issue and try using variable tables instead. Try the following:

```
DELCARE @newSales TABLE 
(
    AddressId INT NOT NULL,
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    Sale REAL NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressId] ASC, [ItemId] ASC, [Date] ASC)
)

INSERT INTO @newSales
SELECT *
FROM myOtherTables
...
```

Comment: I'm not yet sure that my code runs concurrently, but even if it is, I don't understand why I should avoid this? Thanks for the info, I'll try this if I won't find the source of the problem. I just don't want to use table variables because they are very slow in my case due to lack of statistics.

Comment: The issue is that if the code runs simultaneously, the second will try dropping the table created in the first thread. Using variable tables prevents all forms of interference.

Comment: No, the second code won't delete the first table because the Database Engine is appending a numeric suffix to each local temporary table name. ([msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_2))

Comment: I am not familiar with how the names are auto-generated by SQL Server, but perhaps it is time based and some cycles are close enough for it to generate the same name. I am not certain what is causing the issue at all, but I believe using variable tables should give you a fighting chance of resolving it.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it will work, thank you! But think I'll use it as a last-chance solution because I want to understand what's the problem here...